# Is my 3 years old loose leaf tea safe for me to drink?

Tags: storage-lifetime, tea

I have some cinnamon orange tea in my kitchen that has been sitting there for 3 years. Would it still be safe to drink?

It is in a container with a lid.

Comment: Yes it would be safe, see the answers here - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9778/my-tea-bags-are-expired-can-i-still-use-them

Comment: If drinking 3 year old tea was harmful I'd be dead by now.

Comment: I have 15 year old pu erh tea cakes and I'm still alive. As long as it's dry with no mold you are fine...