# I bought a wooden box of individually packaged red ginseng tea, but I checked the box and it expired in 2015! Do you think it's still okay to drink?

Tags: tea

I bought the box from a second hand store. It's a wooden box with 100 3g Korean red ginseng teabags and the wooden box still had a plastic packaging around it. It looks new but the inside smells a little like pva glue?? The other posts on here say tea doesn't really expire, the taste and health benefits just don't last very long after the shelf life. I was worried that red ginseng tea might be different.

Comment: Have you checked that the date is not written in the format YY-MM-DD?

Comment: We can't tell you what is an isn't safe, but generally speaking tea is dried leaves. And assuming that it hasn't become moldy I would imagine that an expiration on such a food item *might indicate* how long it can reasonably assured to be at the peak of freshness/flavor. Beyond that I would be hesitant to say *"sure go for it, drink up!"*

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about this Stack.

Comment: Note the difference between [expiry, sell by, and best before dates](https://www.eufic.org/en/food-safety/article/best-before-use-by-and-sell-by-dates-explained). It's likely that the date you have is a "best before" date and as such just means that the quality of flavour/freshness/rehydration (while steeping) etc, will not be as good as it might have been before the date shown.

Comment: This question comes up every few years.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9778/67